# Specify From when sending an automated Outlook email using SMTP configuration

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, smtp

I need to send an email from an SMTP server so it is from `"Automated Notification <NoReplyEmail@agit.com>"`.

I tried browsing ways to send emails with that From address. Apparently, SMTP is a way. How do I connect it using Outlook?

I did this before using CDO. Is there any way to amend it to Outlook?

```vb
Dim iCfg As CDO.Configuration
Set iCfg = New CDO.Configuration

With iCfg
    .Fields(cdoSMTPServer) = "sgp.smtp.agit.com"
    .Fields(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25
    .Fields(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    .Fields(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 200
    .Fields.Update
End With

Set .Configuration = iCfg
```

Is there any other way I could get `"Automated Notification <NoReplyEmail@agit.com>"` as my From address?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a code where you add the `From` parameter and how you're actually sending the emial.
But based on my experience with `CDO` you will need a `CDO.Message` object.
So try this:

```
Dim cdoMsg AS CDO.Message
Set cdoMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

With cdoMsg
  Set .Configuration = iCfg       '// from the code snipped in the question above
  .From = "NoReplyEmail@agit.com" '// you only need to set this parameter
  .To = "someone@someweb.com"
  .Subject = "Your Subject"
  .TextBody = "Sample Text"
  .Send
End With
```

Take note that you cannot put the alias of the SMTP unless it is set up at your server. So even if you set the `From` parameter like this:

```
.From = """Automated Notification"" <NoReplyEmail@agit.com>"
```

alias will not appear upon receiving mail.